# transform pde into pde with homogenous boundary condition

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Consider $-\Delta u = f $ in $\Omega$ with $u=0$ on $\Gamma_1$ and $u=g$ on $\Gamma_2$.

Consider $u = u_0 + u_g$, where $u_g =g$ on $\Gamma_1$ and $u_0 =0$ on $\Gamma_2$

Then it holds $-\Delta u_0 = f +\Delta u_g   $

with $u_0=0$ on $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$

Why is this the case for the boundary. If I consider $u_0 = u-u_g  $ on $\Gamma_1$.
Then I would get: $u_0= 0- g=-g $

Did missunderstand this procedure?

Comment: It was given as an example in the lecture. With your definition it would make sense then $u_0 = u-u_g = 0-0=0$ on $\Gamma_1$ and $u_0=g-g=0.$

Comment: But for what do I need $u_0 =0$ on $\Gamma_2$ then?

Comment: Perhaps your lecturer (or you) mixed up the $\Gamma_i$ somewhere between the first and the second line above. You want to have $u_g$ the same boundary values as $u$ ($u_g$ is a particular solution to the inhomogeneous problem), such that $u_0 := u-u_g$ has homogeneous boundary values ($0$ everywhere). So we need (as for $u$): $u_g|_{\Gamma_1} = 0$ and $u_g|_{\Gamma_2} = g$.

Comment: So we do not need $u_0$ on $\Gamma_1$ but rather $u_g$ on that part?

Comment: You can also write $u_g|_{\Gamma_1} = 0$ and $u_0|_{\Gamma_2} = 0$ (the other is implicitly given by $u = u_0 + u_g$, as $u$'s values on the boudary are known), but IMHO it's more natural to give $u_g$'s boundary values.

Comment: Thank you very much:)